# java.lang.SecurityException: JSR 177 access for this connection is not permitted

Tags: blackberry, securityexception, sim-card, apdu

I'm trying to communicate with a SIM card using the APDUConnection with the SAT target, but I get this exception:

"java.lang.SecurityException: JSR 177 access for this connection is not permitted"

```
public void Test() {
 APDUConnection acn = null;
 try     {
    //Create an APDUConnection object
    acn = (APDUConnection)  Connector.open("apdu:0;target=SAT");        
    // ...      
 }
 catch( SecurityException e) {
    String exceptionMsg = "SecurityException: " + e.toString();
    System.err.println(exceptionMsg);
 }
 // ...
}
```

I have this problem with the SIM card that I am trying to communicate with, but on other SIM cards, such as my Carrier's (Rogers), I can open the APDU connection just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SIM's ACF (Access Control File) has some restrictions which Roger's SIM doesn't have. You have to sign your midlet by using a certificate path provided by the MNO (SIM owner) in order to access to SAT.

Comment: Another team on the same project is the MNO. Do you have any idea how the OS (BlackBerry in this case) goes about finding out about ACF restrictions? I'm guessing that the OS sends an APDU to get access control information, and the SIM card replies with something. I'll accept the answer if you could give me some clue about that. I wish I had the sources for the BB os, but they are private.